# Create integer sequences defined by 'from' and 'to' vectors

Tags: r, vectorization, sequence

I have two vectors which define start (from) indices and finish (to) indices:

```
Start = c(1, 10, 20)
Finish = c(9, 19, 30)
```

I want to create a list of all `Start:Finish` sequences along the two vectors, i.e. generate the sequences `Start[1]:Finish[1]` (`1:9`); `Start[2]:Finish[2]`, and so on.

```
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
## 
## [[2]]
##  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
## 
## [[3]]
##  [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Preferably in some vectorized way. The values in 'Start' vector will always be larger than the corresponding elements in 'Finish' vector.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use `mapply`:

```
Start = c(1,10,20)
Finish = c(9,19,30)
mapply(":", Start, Finish)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
## 
## [[2]]
##  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
## 
## [[3]]
##  [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
##
```

You could, of course, also use `Vectorize`, but that's just a wrapper for `mapply`. However, `Vectorize` cannot be used with primitive functions, so you'll have to specify `seq.default` rather than `seq`, or `seq.int`.

Example:

```
Vectorize(seq.default)(Start, Finish)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
## 
## [[2]]
##  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
## 
## [[3]]
##  [1] 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
##
```

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, true :-)

Comment: It's not just to save 3 chars, but also to avoid the result being simplified. For instance `mapply(":", c(0,10,20), c(9,19,29))` doesn't produce a `list`. Either use `Map` or add `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`.

Comment: @nicola, good point about the fact that `mapply` defaults to `SIMPLIFY = TRUE`.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with @ColonelBeauvel and @nicola, though you could use `seq` instead of `:`, hence

```
Start = c(1, 10, 20)
Finish = c(9, 19, 30)
Map(seq, Start, Finish)
```