# Is there any other way to solve this Mathematical problem in R?

Tags: r

Calculate the `$\sum_{j=1}^{n}r^j$` where r has been assigned the value `$1.06$`,and compare with `\frac{(1-r^{n+1})}{(1-r)} for $n=10,20$`.

This is what I have done so far.

```
j=c(1:10)
r=1.06
A=r^j
A
sum(A)
compare_with=(1-(1.06)^(11))/(1-(1.06))
compare_with
```

Comment: Can someone tell me why math functions didn't render?

Comment: Try `j <- 0:10` and see the result. Also, if you want to compute the value of the fraction for several values of `n` write a function, `compare_with <- function(n) (1 - 1.06^(n + 1))/(1 - 1.06)`. Then, `compare_with(c(10, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you so much. I have just attended two lectures  in my college so  I was curious how do we input values of n .

Comment: @RuiBarradas I want to calculate sum(A) for different values of n. Code I have written is 
```j <- 1:function(n)
r <- 1.06
A <- (r^j)
sum(A)((c(10,20,30,40)))
compare_with=(r-r^(n+1))/(1-r)
compare_with(c(10,20,30,40))```

Comment: @RuiBarradas can you help me  with this code `n <- c(10,20,30,40)
j <- 1:n
r <- 1.06
A <- r^j
A
sum(A)
`
output doesn't give 4 values but gives one value with warning message 
`In 1:n : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141641/sequence-all-integers-between-two-vectors-in-r

Comment: ```lapply(mapply(":", c(1,1,1,1), c(10,20,30,40)), function(x) sum(1.08^unlist(x)))```

Comment: @beavis11111 I am not yet taught this syntax you used. Can you do some modification in my code ? 
`r=1.06
A <- function(n)(sum(r^(1:n)))
A((c(10,20,30,40)))
compare_with <- function(n) (r - r^(n + 1))/(1 - r)
compare_with(c(10,20,30,40)) `

Comment: ```compare_with <- function(n,r) (r - r^(n + 1))/(1 - r); compare_with(c(10,20,30,40), r=1.08)```

Comment: @beavis11111 I want output of sum as well then I have to compare that both are same thing. Problem is sum isn't picking up all 4 values. I have to compare `A` and `compare_with`

Comment: ```A <- function(n,r)(sum(r^(1:n)));  sapply(c(10,20,30,40), function(x) A(x,r=1.08))``` you have to use `apply` since it is summing inside, when you said you wanted the same thing I assume same `class` ie vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is simpler than what the discussions in the comments are making it look. In R, all arithmetic operations are vectorized, so the code below works for a vector `n`.

```
compare_with <- function(n, r) (r - r^(n + 1))/(1 - r)

n <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
j <- 1:10
r <- 1.06
A <- r^j

sum(A)
#[1] 13.97164

compare_with(n, r)
#[1]  13.97164  38.99273  83.80168 164.04768
```

If the function needs to also be vectorized over `r`, it's once again not that complicated.

```
CompareWith <- Vectorize(compare_with, "r")

r_vec <- c(1.06, 1.08)
CompareWith(n, r_vec)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,]  13.97164  15.64549
#[2,]  38.99273  49.42292
#[3,]  83.80168 122.34587
#[4,] 164.04768 279.78104
```

Answer (score 2):

You have made an error in the formula for `compare_with`.  First of all you define `r` but don't use it in `compare_with`. It is much better to use variables you define so that when you change a value you don't have to change it all over the place with the risk of forgetting to change some part.

Your `compare_with` is wrong. It should read

```
compare_with=(1.06-(1.06)^(11))/(1-(1.06))
```

You can prove this the standard way for geometric series.

Secondly there is absolutely no need to use  `c` in the definition of `j`; just `j <- 1:n` is sufficient. And you should define `n` before you start.

A nicer way of writing your formulas is

```
n <- 10
j <- 1:n
r <- 1.06
A <- r^j
A
sum(A)
compare_with=(r-r^(n+1))/(1-r)
compare_with
```

If you follow @Rui_Barradas's advice the `compare_with` function should be written as:

```
compare_with <- function(n) (r - r^(n + 1))/(1 - r)
```

BTW: In your question you say that `r` has been assigned the value `1.08`. Yourcalculations use the value `1.06`. So what is it?

**Additional method**

To do what you specify in your comment you could do that this way.
Define a function `A` that can take a vector of values for `n` like this

```
A <- function(n) { Asum <- function(n) sum(r^(1:n)); sapply(n,Asum) }
```

Then this will do what you want

```
n <- c(10,20,30,40)
compare_with(n)
A(n)
```

Comment: I want to calculate sum as well for different values n of and then  I have to compare.
`j <- 1:n
r <- 1.06
A <- function(n)sum(r^j)
A((c(10,20,30,40)))
compare_with=(r-r^(n+1))/(1-r)
compare_with(c(10,20,30,40))`

Answer (score 2):

```
j <- 1:10
j.compare <- c(10,20)
sum(1.08^j) #sum
(1-1.08^j.compare)*((1-1.08)^-1) #compare with
```

Comment: can you help me  with this code `n <- c(10,20,30,40)
j <- 1:n
r <- 1.06
A <- r^j
A
sum(A)
`
output doesn't give 4 values but gives one value with warning message 
`In 1:n : numerical expression has 4 elements: only the first used`

Comment: why does sum gives only one value instead of a vector?

Comment: replied on above, have to treat it as multiple vector input, four for your case.